# "Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

Tags: r, regex

I am performing DESeq2 for an scRNA-seq dataset. The contents in cts.split look like so:

"Glial Cells_FLOX_A18_AAACGGGTCAGGCCCA-1" and so forth (14000 contents). Now, I performed this function in order to apply in a loop fashion removing all strings before the first underscore and after the 3rd underscore so that this would appear as: FLOX_A18. I however, have been receiving the following error:

`cts.split.modified<- lapply(cts.split, function(x){ rownames(x)<-gsub(".*_(.*_.*)_.*", '\\1', rownames(x)) t(x)})` 
**
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
**
Any suggestions? Input would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried replacing the row names but this does not work as well. How do I get this function to run?

Comment: don't assign within the function (remove `rownames(x) <-`) and then it should return a vector. from that vector see if there any duplicate values. if there are that is the problem